# Android app with swipable tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I created a simple app but now I want to add swipable tabs. By seeing some Tutorials I made the tabs necessary but I don't know how to insert seperate layouts for different tabs. Can anyone help me with a tutorial?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.cgpa;

import com.example.gpa.R;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter1 mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Semester 1", "Semester 2", "Semester 3" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter1(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

I think its a mess right now.

I want to add the following code to the first tab

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView e1;
    int g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, cr = 0;
    int co1 = 0, co2 = 0, co3 = 0, co4 = 0, co5 = 0, co6 = 0, co7 = 0, co8 = 0,
            co9 = 0;
    String an, ch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        final Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        final Spinner spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        final Spinner spinner5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
        final Spinner spinner6 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner6);
        final Spinner spinner7 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner7);
        final Spinner spinner8 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner8);
        final Spinner spinner9 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner9);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        e1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i1)) {
                    g1 = 10;
                    co1++;
                    if (co1 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;

                } else if ("A".equals(i1)) {
                    g1 = 9;
                    co1++;
                    if (co1 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("B".equals(i1)) {
                    g1 = 8;
                    co1++;
                    if (co1 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("C".equals(i1)) {
                    g1 = 7;
                    co1++;
                    if (co1 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("D".equals(i1)) {
                    g1 = 6;
                    co1++;
                    if (co1 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("E".equals(i1)) {
                    g1 = 5;
                    co1++;
                    if (co1 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("U".equals(i1)) {
                    if (co1 >=1) {
                        cr = cr - 4;
                        co1 = 0;
                    }
                    g1 = 0;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i2)) {
                    g2 = 10;
                    co2++;
                    if (co2 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;

                } else if ("A".equals(i2)) {
                    g2 = 9;

                    co2++;
                    if (co2 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("B".equals(i2)) {
                    g2 = 8;
                    co2++;
                    if (co2 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("C".equals(i2)) {
                    g2 = 7;
                    co2++;
                    if (co2 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("D".equals(i2)) {
                    g2 = 6;
                    co2++;
                    if (co2 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("E".equals(i2)) {
                    g2 = 5;
                    co2++;
                    if (co2 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("U".equals(i2)) {
                    if (co2 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 4;
                        co2 = 0;
                    }
                    g2 = 0;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i3 = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i3)) {
                    g3 = 10;
                    co3++;
                    if (co3 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("A".equals(i3)) {
                    g3 = 9;
                    co3++;
                    if (co3 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("B".equals(i3)) {
                    g3 = 8;
                    co3++;
                    if (co3 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("C".equals(i3)) {
                    g3 = 7;
                    co3++;
                    if (co3 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("D".equals(i3)) {
                    g3 = 6;
                    co3++;
                    if (co3 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("E".equals(i3)) {
                    g3 = 5;
                    co3++;
                    if (co3 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("U".equals(i3)) {
                    if (co3 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 3;
                        co3 = 0;
                    }
                    g3 = 0;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i4 = spinner4.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 10;
                    co4++;
                    if (co4 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("A".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 9;
                    co4++;
                    if (co4 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("B".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 8;
                    co4++;
                    if (co4 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("C".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 7;
                    co4++;
                    if (co4 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("D".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 6;
                    co4++;
                    if (co4 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("E".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 5;
                    co4++;
                    if (co4 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("U".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 0;

                    if (co4 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 3;
                        co4 = 0;
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner5.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i5 = spinner5.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 10;
                    co5++;
                    if (co5 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("A".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 9;
                    co5++;
                    if (co5 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("B".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 8;
                    co5++;
                    if (co5 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("C".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 7;
                    co5++;
                    if (co5 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("D".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 6;
                    co5++;
                    if (co5 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("E".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 5;
                    co5++;
                    if (co5 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("U".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 0;
                    if (co5 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 3;
                        co5 = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner6.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i6 = spinner6.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 10;
                    co6++;
                    if (co6 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;

                } else if ("A".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 9;
                    co6++;
                    if (co6 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;

                } else if ("B".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 8;
                    co6++;
                    if (co6 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("C".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 7;
                    co6++;
                    if (co6 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("D".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 6;
                    co6++;
                    if (co6 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("E".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 5;
                    co6++;
                    if (co6 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;

                } else if ("U".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 0;
                    if (co6 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 4;
                        co6 = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner7.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i7 = spinner7.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 10;
                    co7++;
                    if (co7 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;

                } else if ("A".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 9;
                    co7++;
                    if (co7 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;

                } else if ("B".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 8;
                    co7++;
                    if (co7 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;
                } else if ("C".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 7;
                    co7++;
                    if (co7 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;
                } else if ("D".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 6;
                    co7++;
                    if (co7 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;
                } else if ("E".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 5;
                    co7++;
                    if (co7 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;

                } else if ("U".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 0;
                    if (co7 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 2;
                        co7 = 0;
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner8.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i8 = spinner8.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 10;
                    co8++;
                    if (co8 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;

                } else if ("A".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 9;
                    co8++;
                    if (co8 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;

                } else if ("B".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 8;
                    co8++;
                    if (co8 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;
                } else if ("C".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 7;
                    co8++;
                    if (co8 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;
                } else if ("D".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 6;
                    co8++;
                    if (co8 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;
                } else if ("E".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 5;
                    co8++;
                    if (co8 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;

                } else if ("U".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 0;
                    if (co8 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 2;
                        co8 = 0;
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner9.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i9 = spinner9.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 10;
                    co9++;
                    if (co9 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 1;

                } else if ("A".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 9;
                    co9++;
                    if (co9 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 1;

                } else if ("B".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 8;
                    co9++;
                    if (co9 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 1;
                } else if ("C".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 7;
                    co9++;
                    if (co9 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 1;
                } else if ("D".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 6;
                    co9++;
                    if (co9 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 1;
                } else if ("E".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 5;
                    co9++;
                    if (co9 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 1;

                } else if ("U".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 0;
                    if (co9 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 1;
                        co9 = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int a = (g1 * 4 + g2 * 4 + g3 * 3 + g4 * 3 + g5 * 3 + g6 * 4
                        + g7 * 2 + g8 * 2 + g9 * 1);

                double e11 = a / (float) cr;
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
                an = df.format(e11);
                ch = String.valueOf(an);
                e1.setText("Your GPA is " + ch);

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I want to add this xml for first layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="753dp"
     android:background="@color/orange" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
         android:text="HS6151"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
         android:text="PH6151"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
         android:text="CY6151"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="255dp"
         android:text="GE6151"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView6"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
         android:text="GE6152"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView7"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="345dp"
         android:text="GE6161"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView8"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
         android:text="GE6162"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView9"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="435dp"
         android:text="GE6163"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
         android:entries="@array/Grade"
         android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
         android:entries="@array/Grade"
         android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
         android:entries="@array/Grade"
         android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
         android:entries="@array/Grade"
         android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
         android:entries="@array/Grade"
         android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner6"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
         android:entries="@array/Grade"
         android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner7"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="335dp"
         android:entries="@array/Grade"
         android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner8"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
         android:entries="@array/Grade"
         android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner9"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="425dp"
         android:entries="@array/Grade"
         android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/spinner9"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
         android:text="calculate" />


     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView11"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="SEMESTER I - GPA CALCULATOR"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:textSize="20dp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/editText1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
         android:editable="false"
         android:ems="10"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:inputType="number"
         android:textSize="20dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
         android:text="MA6151"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This my current activity_main.xml. I don't know what to do with it.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" /> 
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already implemented the `viewpager` properly, if you want different fragments for different tabs, you need to change the behaviour of the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 1) {
        return new SomeFragment();
    } else if (position == 2) {
        return new SomeOtherFragment();
    } else {
        return new someOtherO
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more detail? I am not good at Android programming and I am trying to learn now.

Answer (score 0):

I  would recommend you this great library : https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: Can you tell me what to do with it? I am really a newbie.

Comment: This library will allows you to get a great swipeable tabs like Google play app

Comment: Read how to implement a viewpager 
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html
After you have successfully done that, implement the library n OWZY's answer as instructed in the usage section.